# 'Show more results' in UI bootstrap typeahead

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead, angular-ui-typeahead

I'm trying to implement a *Show more results* feature in a typeahead in UI bootstrap. Initially it should load 5 results, then if results exceed 5 I want to show a *Show more results* option to load ALL results from API again (with no limit).

Here's my typeahead definition in the template:

```
<input type="text" name="FullName" id="FullName"
    class="form-control"  autocomplete="false" required="required"
    placeholder="Search by name"
    uib-typeahead="ent as ent.FullName for ent in vm.findEntities($viewValue)"
    typeahead-popup-template-url="entityPopup.tpl.html"
    typeahead-template-url="popupMatch.tpl.html"
    typeahead-on-select="vm.entitySelected($item)"
    ng-model="vm.FullName">
```

I have a variable in the parent-parent controller with the count of the results. `$parent.$parent.vm._entityTotalResults`. If that count exceeds 5 then I want to display a **Show more** button that loads more results and populates them in the typeahead results.

My `entityPopup.tpl.html` is the following:

*Just the default one with one added `<li></li>`*

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" ng-show="isOpen() && !moveInProgress" ng-style="{top: position().top+'px', left: position().left+'px'}" style="display: block;" role="listbox" aria-hidden="{{!isOpen()}}">
      <li ng-repeat="match in matches track by $index" ng-class="{active: isActive($index) }" ng-mouseenter="selectActive($index)" ng-click="selectMatch($index)" role="option" id="{{::match.id}}">
          <div uib-typeahead-match index="$index" match="match" query="query" template-url="templateUrl"></div>
      </li>
      <li ng-show="$parent.$parent.vm._entityTotalResults > 5">SHOW MORE</li>
  </ul>
```

My typeahead function `findEntities()` is the following:

```
vm.findEntities = function findEntities(viewValue, limit) {
  return apiService.findEntities(viewValue, limit)
    .then(function(matches) {
      vm._entityTotalResults = matches.TotalResults;
      return matches.Results;
    });
  };
```

`apiService.findEntities()` is a API function which takes an optional `limit` parameter and returns a $http promise. If it's null it returns all results, otherwise it limits them.

How could I implement this? I haven't found anything on the internet that could direct me into the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the typeahead in a custom directive and provide uibTypeahead with a [custom popup-template](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead)

Answer (score 0):

To get this to work, I had to edit the UI bootstrap source, adding an event listener to the UibTypeaheadController. Above the getMatchesAsync function:

```
originalScope.$on('loadMore', function() {
  hasFocus = true;
  getMatchesAsync(modelCtrl.$viewValue);
});
```

On your list item that show's Load More, I added an ng-click which would emit the loadMore event, scope.$emit('loadMore'). This allows the list of matches to be updated on list more click.